# Java map with multiple values: container class or multiple maps?

Tags: java, performance, dictionary

I'm trying to create a mapping in which a UUID key points to both an object (e.g. some `User` class instance) and auxiliary information about that object (e.g. an `int` and a `String`). There are two obvious implementations of this:

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.UUID;
...
    Map<UUID, User> main = new HashMap<UUID, User>();
    Map<UUID, Integer> aux1 = new HashMap<UUID, Integer>();
    Map<UUID, String> aux2 = new HashMap<UUID, String>();
```

or

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.UUID;
...
    private static class UserInfo { // Nested class
        public final User user;
        public final int aux1;
        public final String aux2;

        public UserInfo(User user, int aux1, String aux2) {
            this.user = user;
            this.aux1 = aux1;
            this.aux2 = aux2;
        }
    }
...
    Map<UUID, UserInfo> main = new HashMap<UUID, UserInfo>();
```

Which is generally considered more performant, in terms of efficiency and memory usage? Or is there a more worthwhile third option?

Comment: The inner class would less memory and it would probably be easier to use and more readable and faster as you only do one lookup (altough not super big as hashmap is O(1))

Comment: That's true, but on the other hand, wouldn't creating a new container object for each new value be more wasteful than just adding the values directly to the underlying array? Apparently this is why a LinkedList generally takes up more memory than an ArrayList despite the ArrayList's leftover capacity.

Comment: The HashMap definitely uses more memory internal HashMap Node uses :final int hash;
        final K key;
        V value;
        Node<K,V> next;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both memory and efficiency, I believe the second option is the better solution. The first solution is creating more `Maps` which use memory, and storing the same `UUID` which use memory.

It is also better for maintainability and readability, which unless performance to the millisecond is critical, is the more important of these. If you bundle the correlated information together, it is easier to determine where you got the information and what it is describing.

Also think about future development for the project, for example adding another descriptor for the user like `aux3`. For the first example you would need to add another hashmap, remember to add to the new hashmap, and remember to pull data from it as you are pulling from the others. This would create a lot of boilerplate for initial set up and access.

```java
uuid = //some uuid
Map<UUID, Double> aux3 = new HashMap<UUID, Double>();

// some code
aux3.put(uuid, 1.0);

// some code ...
aux3.get();
```

But with composition method, you'd only need to remember to add the class property (with successors and mutators), and you are free to use these anywhere. Anytime you access from the user map, you only need I call to `get(uuid)` and you have access to all the associated data.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a solo project & there's only a small possibility that others will see this code in the future, but you're probably right about intuitiveness & maintainability anyway. Although for what it's worth, in the first solution I'm pretty sure the multiple maps would just store multiple references to the same UUID's rather than multiple copies of them.

Comment: It would store references, but references still use memory, and if low memory usage is a priority every little bit helps.

Comment: Even if it is a solo project, help future you and make it easy to refactor and practice good design

Answer (score 0):

This is Subjective topic - evaluate below factors

1. Information Security (just because you mentioned user) - can you keep all the information together
2. depends on what you doing with these Maps and if there are likely to be issues because of later processing

otherwise, generally 2nd option (UserInfo class) is a good to idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "do what you are doing"? I haven't implemented either of these possibilities just yet.